# Does an adverb either modify verbs (not adjectives and adverbs), or modify adjectives and adverbs (not verbs)?

Tags: english, adverbs

From Manning's Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing:

> **Adverbs modify a verb** in the same way that adjectives modify adverb nouns. Adverbs specify place, time, manner or degree:
>
> ```
> (3.22) a. She often travels to Las Vegas.
> b. She allegedly committed perjury.
> c. She started her career oﬀ very impressively.
> ```
>
> Some adverbs, such as often, are not derived from adjectives and lack
>   the suﬃx -ly.
>
> **Some adverbs can also modify adjectives ((3.23a) and (3.23b)) and other adverbs (3.23c)**.
>
> ```
> (3.23) a. a very unlikely event
> b. a shockingly frank exchange
> c. She started her career oﬀ very impressively.
> ```
>
> Certain adverbs like very are specialized to the role of **modifying
>   adjectives and adverbs and do not modify verbs**. They are called
>   degree degree adverbs adverbs. Their distribution is thus quite
>   distinct from other adverbs, and they are sometimes regarded as a
>   separate part of speech called qualiﬁers.

In English, are adverbs classified into two groups:   either modify verbs (not adjectives and adverbs), or modify adjectives and adverbs (not verbs)?

Thanks.

Comment: No; and that’s not what the text says either. If any grouping is implied, it’s one between those who modify verbs and those who don’t; the group that modifies verbs can then be subdivided into those that can also modify adjectives and/or adverbs. But it’s not common, as far as I know, to actually group adverbs in this way.

Comment: can you elaborate and give examples?

Comment: Examples of what? I’m just paraphrasing what the quote in your question says.

Comment: Additionally, some adverbs modify whole predicates.

Comment: And sometimes people will classify a word as an adverb because they can't figure out what else to do with it.

Comment: Leaving the rest aside, I disagree with the gruping of the first set. In fact, "allegedly" is a so-called sentence adverb (with epistemic/evidential function) that modifies the whole sentence, as you can see if you prepose it "allegedly, ...". This does not hold for the others.